# What does it mean for operators to be lineraly independant

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am wondering if I have a sequence $\{ K_i \}_{i=1} ^\infty$ such that each $K_i: H\rightarrow H $ where $H$ is a separable Hilbert space. Then what are some criteria/ definitions for linear independence of the operators?

How I understood linear independence of operators was that $A$ and $B$ are linearly independent if $\langle Ax,x \rangle \not = \alpha \langle Bx,x \rangle$. But that was my understanding only from a asking google, and it seems to be only pairwise one a good criteria for a sequence.

Comment: The standard definition of linear independence from linear algebra is that a set of vectors is linearly independent if for every finite subset $v_1, v_2,\dots v_n$ we have that $\sum_{i \leq n} a_i v_i = 0$ implies that $a_i = 0$ for all $i \leq N$. I think this definition also makes perfect sense for sets of operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your definition, an operator and its dual would always be linearly dependent, since $$\forall x, \left<Ax,x\right>=\left<x,A^*x\right>$$

The correct definition is that $A$ and $B$ are linearly independent if there is no couple $(\alpha,\beta)\neq (0,0)$ such that $$\forall x, \alpha A(x)+\beta B(x)=0$$

For a larger family, this definition extends straightforwardly: $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is linearly independent iff there is no collection $(\alpha_i)_{i=1}^n$ not all zero such that $$\forall x, \Sigma \alpha_i A_i(x)=0$$

Comment: I see, and is this equivalent to say that  this would be equivalent to say that $\bigcap_i range(A_i) = \{0\}$?

Comment: @kori Any two rotations in the plane with different angles modulo $\pi $ are linearly independent,  yet their ranges are *equal*.